# Commands to freeze display / make computer unresponsive

Tags: freeze

In order to implement a sleep procrastination tool, I'd like to have a mechanism to make Ubuntu unresponsive to any inputs for a certain timeframe.

At best the command would make the computer unresponsive for power button inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: BIOS does not relinquish the power button input. Ubuntu knows that the button has been pressed, but cannot prevent a force-poweroff by the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks :).
Is there any way to make Ubuntu unresponsive for keyboard (other than power button) and mouse inputs for a timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

the best solution that I've found is xtrlock. Unresponsive to any keyboard / mouse input besides password input.

However you can bypass password unlock by looping the command for a certain timeframe.